# R zoo package: na.approx changing length of vector when NA are in the beginning

Tags: r, zoo

The zoo package has the function na.approx (or na.spline) which replaces NAs in your data with either approx or spline.

One potential argument is `maxgap` which gives the biggest gap to fill. This works fine, except that if the NAs are in the beginning of the vector, the function changes the length of the vector.

For example:

```
require(zoo)
x <- 1:20 + rnorm(20)
x1 <- x
x1[5] <- x1[6] <- NaN
length(na.approx(x1, maxgap = 1)) == length(x) # TRUE
x2 <- x
x2[1] <- x2[2] <- NaN
length(na.approx(x2, maxgap = 1)) == length(x) # FALSE
```

This is problematic when using this function with data frames. For example:

```
require(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(A = 1:20, B = x1)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(B_fill = na.approx(B, maxgap = 1))

df2 <- tibble(A = 1:20, B = x2)
df2 %>% 
  mutate(B_fill = na.approx(B, maxgap = 1))
# Error: Column `B_fill` must be length 20 (the number of rows) or one, not 18
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I was asking this question, I found the answer, just change the `na.rm` argument.

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(B_fill = na.approx(B, maxgap = 1, na.rm = FALSE))
```